# What's wrong with my understanding of the scheme $\text{Isom}(E_\lambda, E_{\lambda'})$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ be the moduli stack of elliptic curves (over the complex numbers). Define
$$\begin{eqnarray*} X &:=& \Bbb{A}^1_{\lambda} - \{0,1\}\\
X' &=& \Bbb{A}^1_{\lambda'} - \{0,1\}.\end{eqnarray*} $$
There are morphisms $X \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ and  $X' \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ given by  the families of curves
$$\begin{eqnarray*} E_\lambda := V(y^2 - x(x-1)(x-\lambda)) \\
E_{\lambda' }:= V(y^2 - x(x-1)(x-\lambda')).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

By results of Grothendieck, we know that the fiber product $\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda}, E_{\lambda'}) :=  X \times_{\mathcal{M}_{1,1}} X'$
is a scheme. Its $T$-points are given by 
$$\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda}, E_{\lambda'})(T) = (T \to X ,T \to X',  {E_{\lambda}}_T \stackrel{\simeq}{\to} {E_{\lambda'}}_T   ) .$$
The isomorphism above between ${E_{\lambda}}_T$ and ${E_{\lambda'}}_T$ is a $T$-isomorphism.

> > My goal  is to try and understand why $X \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ is not étale. To do this, it is enough to show that $\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda},E_{\lambda'}) \to X$ is not \'{e}tale.

Since the automorphisms of any elliptic curve in Legendre form are given by $y \mapsto cy$ and $x \mapsto ax +b$, I can see that the scheme $\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda},E_{\lambda'})$ is given by the following conditions in $\Bbb{A}^5:$

$$\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda},E_{\lambda'}) = \operatorname{Spec} \frac{\Bbb{C}[\lambda, \frac{1}{\lambda}, \frac{1}{1-\lambda},\lambda', \frac{1}{\lambda'}, \frac{1}{1-\lambda'},a,\frac{1}{a},b,c]}{(j(\lambda) - j(\lambda'), f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)}. $$

The polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ are obtained from equating the coefficients of the relation
$$ x(x-1)(x-\lambda') = \frac{(ax+b)(ax+b-1)(ax+b-\lambda)}{c^2}.$$

Explicitly, they are given by:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f_1 &=& a^3 - c^2 \\
f_2 &=& 3a^2b - a^2 \lambda - a^2 + a^3(\lambda' + 1) \\
f_3 &=& 3ab^2 - 2ab\lambda - 2ab + a\lambda -a^3\lambda'\\
f_4 &=& b^3 - b^2\lambda - b^2 + b\lambda.
\end{eqnarray*} $$

Now if I compute the fiber of the map $\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda}, E_{\lambda'}) \to X$ over the $\lambda = -1$ ($j = 1728$), I get the non-reduced scheme

$$\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda}, E_{\lambda'})_{-1} = \operatorname{Spec} \frac{\Bbb{C}[\lambda', \frac{1}{\lambda'}, \frac{1}{1-\lambda'},a,\frac{1}{a}, b,c]}{ \left((2 \lambda'-1)^2 (\lambda'+1)^2 (\lambda'-2)^2,f_1,f_2',f_3',f_4'\right)}$$
where

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f_1 &=& a^3 - c^2 \\
f_2' &=& 3b +a (\lambda'+1) \\
f_3' &=& 3b^2 - a^2\lambda' - 1\\
f_4' &=& b^3 - b.
\end{eqnarray*} $$
Hence $X \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ is ramified.

> > **However:** On the other hand, I have computed the cardinality of the fiber $\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda},E_{\lambda'}) \to X$ to always be 12.

Indeed consider the $\Bbb{C}$-point of $X$ corresponding to $\lambda = -1$. There are three possibilities for $\lambda'$, namely $-1,2,1/2$. An elliptic curve with $j$-invariant 1728 has automorphism group of order 4, and so the fiber over $-1$ has cardinality $3\times 4 = 12$. The story is the same for the other values of $\lambda$.

> > **My question is:** Why am I always getting 12? I am not taking into account some non-reduced issue here? I am also confused because in my head, the fiber cardinality should jump for a ramified morphism.
> >
> > **Edit** I was wrong previously. The fiber over $\lambda = -1$ is reduced, as Macaulay2 tells me (using the command isNormal) that the same ring with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$ is normal, hence reduced. Tensoring with $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ still [preserves reducedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308015/how-to-show-the-tensor-product-of-reduced-k-algebras-must-be-reduced) (since $\Bbb{Q}$ is perfect). The key point is that the element $(2\lambda'-1)(\lambda'+1)(\lambda'-2)$ is already in the ideal $(f_1,f_2',f_3',f_4')$ (also confirmed by Macaulay2).

Comment: Forget about the messy equations. Etaleness of a map to the DM moduli stack says exactly that formal fibers of the family are the universal deformations.  In this case it is formally smooth of relative dimension 1, so it is equivalent to check if the first-order deformation of each geometric fiber is nontrivial.  Bringing in $X'$ is a red herring; forget about it.  But why do you think it is not etale? After all, every elliptic curve over a $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$-scheme *does* acquire "Legendre form" over an etale cover. Do you know the size of the automorphism group of  a "Legendre structure"?

Comment: @nfdc23 I'm very much a beginner in deformation theory - Why would having nontrivial first order deformations imply that the formal fibers are universal deformations? Here, do you mean "nontrivial first order deformations" *inside* $E_\lambda$? Is that the same as $E_\lambda$ not being isotrivial?

Comment: @oxeimon: I meant it as I wrote it:  if the deformation theory is "rigid" (no nontrivial automorphisms *as deformations*) and formally smooth of relative dimension 1 then a formal deformation over a complete dvr that is nontrivial to first order must be a universal deformation.  This is a basic exercise.  I don't claim any relation to isotriviality, which cannot be detected at the infinitesimal level.  (I'm not sure what you mean by "inside $E_{\lambda}$.)

Comment: @nfdc23 I don't know any deformation theory, so unfortunately I didn't understand much of your comment above. The only way at the moment I have of seeing that a representable map from a scheme to a stack is not \'{e}tale is by base changing to a scheme and seeing that the map is not \'{e}tale there. This is why I introduced $X'$ above. As for why I think the map $X \to \mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ is not \'{e}tale, I thought I would run into issues for those elliptic curves with $j=  1728,0$. After all, this map should be thought of as a "j-invariant map" from $X$ to $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$, and we know

Comment: @nfdc23 (cont'd) that the usual $j$-invariant map from $X \to \Bbb{A}^1$ is ramified.

Comment: @BenLim Looking at your calculation: In the coordinate ring for $\mathrm{Isom}$, I would explicitly invert $a$ and/or $c$, and *not* insert the $j(\lambda)=j(\lambda')$ relation.  (The $j$ relation will hold automatically in the ring, since this presents the universal isomorphism).  Also, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are not quite right.

Comment: @BenLim Yes, in principle.  However, explicitly introducing the $j$-relation can't hurt (since it is true), so the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @nfdc23 Is there any chance you could provide a reference or an explanation for why formal deformations in our situation over complete dvr's which are nontrivial to first order must be universal?

Comment: @CharlesRezk I have corrected the $f_2$ and $f_3$. I'll check my calculation of the fiber again.

Comment: @nfdc23 Also, wouldn't your argument imply that *any* nontrivial family of elliptic curves over any base $B$ gives an etale morphism $B\rightarrow\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$? Do you have an example of a nontrivial family whose first order deformations are all trivial?

Comment: @oxeimon: No such conclusion follows from my assertion; e.g., for any family over an open subset of $\mathbf{A}^1$ containing 0, the pullback by $t \rightarrow t^2$ is trivial to first order over 0. Nothing I said is related to a "nontrivial family whose first-order deformations are all zero" (impossible in char. 0).  As for a reference for my assertion (which relies crucially on the deformation theory being formally smooth of relative dimension 1), I have none: I noticed it when teaching myself deformation theory as a student (and am sure many others do to; it is at the level of an exercise).

Comment: @BenLim: Teach yourself what a "Legendre structure" is (e.g,, read relevant parts of the book of Katz & Mazur as Javanpeykar suggests), check their rigidity, and then conclude for the same reason as for $Y_1(N) \rightarrow M_{1,1}$ to be etale for $N$ not too small.  To analyze local structure (such as etaleness of a morphism) with any interesting moduli schemes in a good way one should first understand basic descent theory and deformation theory (e.g., how would you construct the scheme $Y_1(N)$ over $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$ and prove it is smooth?), so the situation with stacks is no different.

Comment: @BenLim How do you know it is non-reduced?  I think your first relation (involving $\lambda'$) is actually in the ideal generated by $f_1',\dots,f_4'$, in which case it actually is reduced.

Comment: @CharlesRezk I think you're right. Macaulay2 says that $(2\lambda'-1)(\lambda'+1)(\lambda'-2)$ is in that ideal.

Answer (score 8):

Let $Leg: \mathbb P^1-\{0,1,\infty\}\to \mathcal M_{1,1}$ be the Legendre map. (This associates to $\lambda$ the elliptic curve given by $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$.)

1. The coarse moduli space map $j:\mathcal M_{1,1}\to \mathbb A^1$ is of degree $1/2$.
2. The morphism $\mathbb P^1-\{0,1,\infty\}\to \mathbb A^1$ is of degree $6$. (Indeed, given a $j$-invariant, there are precisely 6 possibilities for the $\lambda$-invariant of that curve: $\lambda$, $1/\lambda$, $1-\lambda$, $1/(1-\lambda)$, $\lambda/(1-\lambda)$ and $(1-\lambda)/\lambda$.) In other words, the degree of $j\circ L$ is $6$.

It follows that the degree of $L$ is the degree of $j\circ L$ divided by the degree of $j$. This gives $6\times 2 = 12$.

Comment: @BenLim Concerning degrees of maps of stacks: consider $G$ a finite group. What would you say the degree of $\{pt\} \to BG$ is? And what about $BG\to \{pt\}$?

Comment: @BenLim Concerning your confusion: The Legendre map is etale. An elliptic curve in Legendre form has rational $2$-torsion, and any isomorphism of an elliptic curve respecting all of the $2$-torsion points has to be $\pm 1$. A proof of this can be found in Katz-Mazur. (Compare this to the fact that an automorphism of an elliptic curve respecting all of the $n$-torsion points ($n>2$) has to be trivial.)

Comment: Ok. However, if it indeed is \'{e}tale, then why am I getting that the fiber of $\text{Isom}(E_{\lambda}, E_{\lambda'}) \to X$ over $\lambda = -1$ is non-reduced?

Comment: @BenLim (Here's me trying to explaining degrees.) The map $\{pt\} \to [\{pt\}/G]$ is of degree $\# G$. The composition with the coarse map $[\{pt\}/G] \to \{pt\}$ is the identity. So  this means that the "degree" of $BG \to \{pt\} $ is $1/\# G$. You could think of the "point" of $BG$ as a $1/\# G$-th point. There are some other answers on Mathoverflow explaining this. Look up "groupoid cardinality" for instance.

Comment: @BenLim I can't see where your mistake is in your computation at the moment. In any case, there has to be a mistake because $Isom_S(E,E^\prime)\to S$ is a finite unramified morphism of schemes, whenever $S$ is a scheme and $E$ and $E^\prime $ are elliptic curves over $S$. (Note that $Isom_S(E,E^\prime)$ is the sheaf of isomorphisms respecting the zero section.) Are you sure you are computing the scheme-theoretic fibre correctly?

Comment: I will check my calculations. In any case, my isomorphisms above will always respect the zero section since i'm working in affine charts of my curve.